# Deploying Rails app with Capistrano 3 with git repository on the same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano3

I am deploying to a server using Capistrano v3.
I have git repository on the same server I am deploying to.

In Capistrano v2 I had this:

```
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "/home/myuser/repos/myrepo.git"
set :local_repository, "file://."
set :branch, 'master'
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/apps/myapp"
server 'myserver.com', :app, :web, :primary => true
```

How to do this with Capistrano v3 ?

My site on my home computer is also a git repository synchronized with the git repository on the server.

Comment: seems like I can't deploy from a repository on my server.

Answer (score 1):

Since the newer version, Capistrano 3, there have been a bunch of minute changes. (Fairly typical is what I'm finding out now in the RoR world).

You use **repo_url** instead of **repository.**

So in your deploy.rb, try replacing

```
     set :repository, "git@github.com:username/appname.git"  # Your clone URL
```

with

```
     set :repo_url, "git@github.com:username/appname.git"  # Your clone URL
```

Hopefully this works! It worked for me.

Comment: I don't want to use github.com. I am using my server as a GIT repository. I tried this: 'set :repo_url, "/var/www/repos/mysite.git" '. but it shows the error: "cd /var/www/apps/myapp/repo... - not a git repository"

Comment: I was using 'repository' and receiving the error ```fatal: 'HEAD' does not appear to be a git repository```. After changing to ```repor_url``` the error was solved.